# ChildBrowser crashes when targeting all HREF tags in a class

Tags: javascript, cordova, childbrowser

I have been using ChildBrowser happily on my code with no issues through the following function:

```
var app = {
    ready: false,
    initialize: function() {
        this.bind();
    },
    bind: function() {
        document.addEventListener('deviceready', this.deviceready, false);
    },
    deviceready: function() {
        app.report('deviceready');
        app.report('Installing child browser');
        app.ready = true;
        //ChildBorwser init
        cb = ChildBrowser.install();
    },
    report: function(id) { 
    console.log("report:" + id);
    }
};

var layout = {
    showUrl: function(url) {
        if(app.ready == true){
            window.plugins.childBrowser.showWebPage(url);
            event.preventDefault();
            event.stopImmediatePropagation();
            return false;
        }
        else { document.location.href = url; return false; }
    },
}
```

But I get an Xcode error when I try to call the function outside of my javascript 'layout' object, like this:

```
$('.text a').on('click', function(e) { 
    e.preventDefault();
    var thisUrl = $('.text a').attr('href'); 
    layout.showUrl(thisUrl);
});
```

The Xcode error that I get in both simulator and device is:

*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Application tried to present modally an active controller .'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x167012 0x25a0e7e 0x48b721 0x48c777 0x48c7b7 0x35fd 0x6d914 0x6d147 0x6cd2d 0x6ce96 0x6cdd3 0x25b46b0 0x113c035 0xeaf3f 0xea96f 0x10d734 0x10cf44 0x10ce1b 0x33d17e3 0x33d1668 0x3a265c 0x283c 0x2795)
libc++abi.dylib: terminate called throwing an exception.

Answer (score 0):

```
<script src="cordova.js"></script>
<script charset="utf-8" src="Plugins/Child Browser/childbrowser.js"></script>

function onDeviceReady() {
    window.plugins.childBrowser.showWebPage("http://www.google.com");
}
```

See this :
https://github.com/Icenium/sample-childbrowser/tree/master/sample-childbrowser

Comment: I am using Xcode, not Icenium, could you elaborate on your answer please?